# Travis CI: "Unable to locate package python-opencv" Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

On a normal non-virtualenv Ubuntu machine I can run:

```
sudo apt-get install python-opencv
```

And then from Python 2.7 I can run `import cv2`.  Success!

But when I try to do the very same thing in my `.travis.yml` file for automated testing, I get the error:

> E: Unable to locate package python-opencv

**How can I get apt-get to locate `python-opencv` in my Travis-CI build?**

I've tried the following; all were unsuccessful:

1. From https://askubuntu.com/questions/339217/, I tried appending these lines to `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

   ```
   echo "deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main restricted universe" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
   echo "deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise restricted main multiverse universe" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
   echo "deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates main restricted universe" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
   echo "deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates restricted main multiverse universe" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
   ```
2. From [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130620145414/http://www.neuroforge.co.uk/index.php/getting-started-with-python-a-opencv) I tried adding these lines right before:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
   sudo add-apt-repository python-opencv
   ```
3. Following [this](http://danielnouri.org/notes/2012/11/23/use-apt-get-to-install-python-dependencies-for-travis-ci/), with updated method from [here](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/2219), I tried using this instead of `2.7`:

`python:
      - "2.7_with_system_site_packages"`

(My full [`.travis.yml` file is here](https://github.com/openworm/movement_validation/blob/a1c6145790a7f5a431128c2d9a26070111fd3168/.travis.yml).)

**Update**

Burhan Khalid's answer did get OpenCV installed, so the error went away.  However, then when I tried find the package using `import cv2` it still couldn't find it, because the Travis-CI build machine is wrapped in a virtualenv.  So we can't access packages outside of our hermetically-sealed build environment.

So I build from source. (References: [here](https://github.com/kevin-brown/blog.kevin-brown.com/blob/2d5296a8c1ac76dc5cbd2b98d765749c043fc521/_posts/2014-09-27-building-and-installing-opencv-3.markdown), [here](https://github.com/kashefy/elm/blob/76dbd0214dbab91a7de3bdd94767ef08aa67d0f4/.travis.yml) and [here](https://gist.github.com/itguy51/4239282))

Here's how to do it in the `.travis.yml` file:

```
env:
  global:
    # Dependencies
    - DEPS_DIR="`readlink -f $TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR/..`"
    - OPENCV_BUILD_DIR=$DEPS_DIR/opencv/build
```

And then, in the `before_install` section:

```
  - travis_retry git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/Itseez/opencv.git $DEPS_DIR/opencv
  - mkdir $OPENCV_BUILD_DIR && cd $OPENCV_BUILD_DIR

  - |
      if [[ $TRAVIS_PYTHON_VERSION == 2.7 ]]; then 
        cmake -DBUILD_TIFF=ON -DBUILD_opencv_java=OFF -DWITH_CUDA=OFF -DENABLE_AVX=ON -DWITH_OPENGL=ON -DWITH_OPENCL=ON -DWITH_IPP=ON -DWITH_TBB=ON -DWITH_EIGEN=ON -DWITH_V4L=ON -DBUILD_TESTS=OFF -DBUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$(python -c "import sys; print(sys.prefix)") -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=$(which python) -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=$(python -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_inc; print(get_python_inc())") -DPYTHON_PACKAGES_PATH=$(python -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print(get_python_lib())") ..
      else
        cmake -DBUILD_TIFF=ON -DBUILD_opencv_java=OFF -DWITH_CUDA=OFF -DENABLE_AVX=ON -DWITH_OPENGL=ON -DWITH_OPENCL=ON -DWITH_IPP=ON -DWITH_TBB=ON -DWITH_EIGEN=ON -DWITH_V4L=ON -DBUILD_TESTS=OFF -DBUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$(python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.prefix)") -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=$(which python3) -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=$(python3 -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_inc; print(get_python_inc())") -DPYTHON_PACKAGES_PATH=$(python3 -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print(get_python_lib())") ..
      fi
  - make -j4
  - sudo make install

  - echo "/usr/local/lib" | sudo tee -a /etc/ld.so.conf.d/opencv.conf
  - sudo ldconfig
  - echo "PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig" | sudo tee -a /etc/bash.bashrc
  - echo "export PKG_CONFIG_PATH" | sudo tee -a /etc/bash.bashrc
  - export PYTHONPATH=$OPENCV_BUILD_DIR/lib/python3.3/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After:

```
sudo add-apt-repository python-opencv
```

You need

```
sudo apt-get update
```

So that the new repository information is correctly updated; before you can add packages from that repository.

Comment: This installs openCV on the machine, but it's no good because it's isolated from my Travis-CI virtualenv.  See the update in my question.